# iptables/firewall-cmd DROP rules set last block ip rule set before

Tags: iptables, firewall, firewalld, port

As follow is the list of the iptables rules that I have :

```
# firewall-cmd --direct --get-all-rules
ipv4 filter INPUT 0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
...
...
ipv4 filter INPUT 1 -d 127.0.0.1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 4118 -j ACCEPT
ipv4 filter INPUT 2 -i lo -j DROP
ipv4 filter FORWARD 0 -j DROP
ipv4 filter OUTPUT 0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
...
...
ipv4 filter OUTPUT 1 -d 127.0.0.1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 4118 -j ACCEPT
ipv4 filter OUTPUT 2 -o lo -j DROP
```

When I start my dsa command I get the following erreur message :

```
dsa_control
couldn't connect to 127.0.0.1:4118 (-1: Socket reset)
```

`ss -ntl` gives :

```
State            Recv-Q           Send-Q                      Local Address:Port                       Peer Address:Port
LISTEN           0                128                               0.0.0.0:111                             0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN           0                128                               0.0.0.0:22                              0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN           0                128                                  [::]:111                                [::]:*
LISTEN           0                5                                       *:4118                                  *:*
LISTEN           0                128                                  [::]:22                                 [::]:*
```

Everything works fine when I remove the DROP input and output rules. Any idea of how these DROP rules still block ip 127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: Since input/output is heavily filtered, did you think about everything? Example: DNS? You'd better be exhaustive in your description and replace `....` with all the actual ports you are handling. Then you should describe what is `dsa_control` and what it's supposed to do, how... Also why use firewalld if it's to put iptables rules? You should use iptables directly, because you force people answering to know well both (I don't have a good knowledge of firewalld).

Comment: Is there any service listening at port 4118/tcp? What's the output of `ss -ntl`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A rule was indeed missing. I had to add the option --dport in addition to --sport for the port to be open as needed.

Comment: Please use english so others can understand the answer